# Noun to adjective and adjective to adverb

Tags: parts-of-speech

For example, there are biological science and scientific news. Can I say it 'biologically scientific news'?

In this context, 'biological' means 'relating to biology,' and 'scientific' means 'relating to science.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

There are situations where you can put an adverb, adjective and noun together, for example "statistically significant data".

Biological science, however, is a [compound noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm), made up of an adjective and a noun. You can't just convert each of the parts to something else, and expect it to be a "compound adjective" or whatever.

Fortunately, there is no limit to the number of words in a compound noun, so it's perfectly OK to just tack another noun on the end. In this case, you get "biological science news".

Comment: When would 'biological science news" be preferable to 'biology news'?

Comment: "Biological science" a compound noun?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that's a good question. I thought about it for a while, and considered changing it to **political science**, which is clearly different to **politics**. In fact, biological science is not a tautology. biology (bio + logy) s the study of living things, and science is "knowledge from the careful study of...." so biological science is knowledge from the study of biological things.

Comment: @BillJ Yes. A simple adverb+noun is commutative- you can change the structure without changing the meaning. " I am eating a green apple" -> "I am eating an apple that is green". A compound noun is not commutative "I am studying political science" does not mean the same as "I am studying science that is political".

Comment: In for example, "I'm interested in biological science", it's not a compound word, but a syntactic construction consisting of modifier+head. Compounds are different; they consist of two bases, cf. "green house" vs "greenhouse".